# Possible to have strings for enums?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I want to have an enum as in:

```
enum FilterType
{
   Rigid = "Rigid",
   SoftGlow = "Soft / Glow",
   Ghost = "Ghost",
}
```

How to achieve this? Is there a better way to do this? It's gonna be used for an instance of an object where it's gonna be serialized/deserialized. It's also gonna populate a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using System.ComponentModel;   
enum FilterType
{
    [Description("Rigid")]
    Rigid,
    [Description("Soft / Glow")]
    SoftGlow,
    [Description("Ghost")]
    Ghost ,
}
```

You can get the value out like this

```
public static String GetEnumerationDescription(Enum e)
{
  Type type = e.GetType();
  FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(e.ToString());
  DescriptionAttribute[] da = (DescriptionAttribute[])(fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false));
  if (da.Length > 0)
  {
    return da[0].Description;
  }
  return e.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. You could even have this as an extension method for all enums.

Comment: Thanks.. I have quite a few static methods that I use on my current project to deal with enums like this. I never thought of using an extension method though. Ill have to give that a try

Comment: It is a good practice to serialize this by...defining one more attribute....on [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("Rigid")] ...[Description("Rigid")]Rigid,...etc.

Answer (score 9):

No, but if you want to scope "const" strings and use them like an enum, here's what I do:

```
public static class FilterType
{
   public const string Rigid = "Rigid";
   public const string SoftGlow =  "Soft / Glow";
   public const string Ghost ="Ghost";
}
```

Comment: This is how I've done this in the past as well, works well for most purposes.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that I can't see how you could automatically populate a drop down. With a little work you at least have the option of iterating the values of an enum.

Comment: Or you could define a static string Values[] array.

Comment: DV for NO in ..."No, but if you want to scope "const" strings ..."

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can cheat like this:

```
public enum FilterType{
   Rigid,
   SoftGlow,
   Ghost
}
```

And then when you need their string values you can just do `FilterType.Rigid.ToString()`.

Comment: Doing it this way (which I'm guilty of too) shows the user text without spaces/special characters (SoftGlow as opposed to "Soft / Glow"), which I'm sure he wants to be able to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with extension methods, you can easily do what you're after:

```
//Can return string constants, the results of a Database call, 
//or anything else you need to do to get the correct value 
//(for localization, for example)
public static string EnumValue(this MyEnum e) {
    switch (e) {
        case MyEnum.First:
            return "First Friendly Value";
        case MyEnum.Second:
            return "Second Friendly Value";
        case MyEnum.Third:
            return "Third Friendly Value";
    }
    return "Horrible Failure!!";
}
```

This way you can do:

```
Private MyEnum value = MyEnum.First;
Console.WriteLine(value.EnumValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  C# only allows integral enum types (int, short, long, etc.).  You can either create a lightweight "enum-like" class or use static constants.

```
static class FilterTypes
{
    public const string Rigid = "Rigid";
    // ...
}

// or ...

class FilterType
{
    static readonly FilterType RigidFilterType = new FilterType("Rigid");

    string name;

    FilterType(string name)  // private constructor
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static FilterType Rigid
    {
        get { return FilterType.RigidFilterType; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enums are always linked to an integer value. So no.
You can do FilterType.Rigid.ToString() to obtain the string value although it can't be localized directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Enum name as a string like this

```
FilterType myType = FilterType.Rigid;
String strType = myType.ToString();
```

However, you may be stuck with the Camel Case/Hungarian notation, but you can easily convert that to a more user friendly String using a method like this (Not the prettiest solution, I would be grateful for input on optimizing this):

```
Public Shared Function NormalizeCamelCase(ByVal str As String) As String

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
        Return String.Empty
    End If

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim upperCount As Integer = 0
    Dim otherCount As Integer = 0
    Dim normalizedString As String = str

    While i < normalizedString.Length

        If Char.IsUpper(normalizedString, i) Then
            ''Current char is Upper Case
            upperCount += 1
            If i > 0 AndAlso Not normalizedString(i - 1).Equals(" "c) Then
                ''Current char is not first and preceding char is not a space
                ''...insert a space, move to next char
                normalizedString = normalizedString.Insert(i, " ")
                i += 1
            End If
        ElseIf Not Char.IsLetter(normalizedString, i) Then
            otherCount += 1
        End If

        ''Move to next char
        i += 1

    End While

    If upperCount + otherCount = str.Length Then
        ''String is in all caps, return original string 
        Return str
    Else
        Return normalizedString
    End If

End Function
```

If that's still not pretty enough, you may want to look into Custom Attributes, which can be retrieved using Reflection...

Answer (score 1):

In the System.ComponentModel namespace there is a class DescriptionAttribute that works well here.

```
enum FilterType
{
   Rigid,
   [Description("Soft / Glow")]
   SoftGlow,
   Ghost,
}
```

Then to get the description and fail over to the ToString()

```
var descriptionAttribute = Value.GetType()
 .GetField(Value.ToString())
 .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
 .OfType <DescriptionAttribute>()
 .FirstOrDefault()??new DescriptionAttribute(Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not outright possible. However you can fake it using an array.

First, Create you enum the way you would a regular one:

```
public enum Regexs
{ 
   ALPHA = 0, 
   NUMERIC = 1, 
   etc.. 
}
```

Then you create an array that holds the values corresponding to the enum values:

```
private static string[] regexs = new string[]
{
   "[A-Za-z]",
   "[0-9]",
   "etc"...
}
```

Then you can access your strings through the enum value:

```
public void runit(Regexs myregexEnum)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex( regexs [(int)myregexEnum] );
}
```

Comment: i don't think that this solution has any benefit against the already (two and a half year) accepted answer, cause now you have to keep two places in sync if you make any changes to the enum.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

> The approved types for an enum are
>   byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint,
>   long, or ulong.

However, you can retrieve the declared name of an enum with the Enum class:

```
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(FilterType), FilterType.Rigid);
```

If this doesn't work for you, a collection of string constants collected in a class might.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Attribute over the values

```
[System.ComponentModel.Description("Rigid")]
```

example:

```
 enum FilterType
{
   [System.ComponentModel.Description("Rigid")]
   Rigid,
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Soft / Glow")]
   SoftGlow,
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Ghost")]
   Ghost
}
```

and use Reflection to get the descriptions.

Enum extension method:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum en)
    {
        var type = en.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            var attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
        return en.ToString();
    }
```

use it:

```
FilterType = FilterType.Rigid;
            string description= result.GetDescription();
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Shaun Bowe's example you can also do this in C# 3 with an extension method for enum (I did not come up with and cannot, for the life of me, remember where I did).

Create an Attribute:

```
public class DisplayTextAttribute : Attribute {
  public DisplayTextAttribute(String text) {
  Text = text;
  }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Create an extension:

```
public static class EnumHelpers {
  public static string GetDisplayText(this Enum enumValue) {
    var type = enumValue.GetType();
    MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumValue.ToString());

    if (memberInfo == null || memberInfo.Length == 0)
      return enumValue.ToString();

    object[] attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayTextAttribute), false);
    if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
      return enumValue.ToString();

    return ((DisplayTextAttribute)attributes[0]).Text;
  }
}
```

I've found this to be really tidy solution.
In your enum add the following:

```
enum FilterType{
  Rigid,
  [DisplayText("Soft / Glow")]
  SoftGlow,
  Ghost
}
```

You could then access `FilterType.GetDisplayText()` which will pull back the string for the unattributed enums and the displayText for the ones with attributes.

Comment: Interesting approach.  Just make sure you don't use this code in a "high performance" path, since it's quite expensive to do reflection calls.